# is it possible to override the automatic formatter in go

Tags: go

In a GO struct I personally do not like the id fields following the convension - UserID.  Is there a way to tell the GO formatter that UserId is ok and to stop giving me a warning?

Comment: ah you are probably correct, sorry I am just learning go and was using Atom.  I followed the steps to run the formatter on save.

Comment: `golint` (which it seems you're referring to) has no options, and is only to provide suggestions that match the preferred style guide. Turn it off if you don't like its suggestions. However, I would still run it occasionally to see if there are any other style issues you may have in your code.

Comment: If you follow the Go naming conventions, `UserID` is the correct name for something containing a "user identity" (`ID` is short for "identity" and should be all-uppercase) and `UserId` is the correct name for a variable containing a users's id (that is, the most basic part of the user's personality).

Comment: I don't have control over the Database which uses stuff like UserId, I know that I can create maps and stuff in the struct.  I was worried about a possible performance hit when moving from one map to the next.   

Example:  Database UserId, go code UserID, json output UserId

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just fork the `golint` repo and modify the `lintNames` function as you like: https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/32a87160691b3c96046c0c678fe57c5bef761456/lint.go#L510

My suggestion: Don't override conventions or your code will look alien to other Gophers!